# Have the Little Fuzzy sequels been published as ebooks?

Tags: little-fuzzy, john-f-carr

I've been rereading H. Beam Piper's "Little Fuzzy" novels.

He wrote three:

- Little Fuzzy
- Fuzzy Sapiens
- Fuzzies and Other People (which was lost and published posthumously)

And then there were two unauthorized sequels, written before the third book was found:

- Fuzzy Bones, by William Tuning
- Golden Dreams: A Fuzzy Odyssey,by Ardith Mayhair

And then three authorized sequels, written after the third book had been found:

- Fuzzy Ergo Sum, by Wolfgang Diehr
- Caveat Fuzzy, by Wolgang Diehr
- Fuzzy Conundrum, by Wolfgang Diehr and John F. Carr

I've only found the first two as ebooks.

Have any of the others ever been published as ebooks?

Are they likely to be?

Comment: Sorry, my mistake.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first two books in the [series](https://www.goodreads.com/series/49377-fuzzy-sapiens) have been legitimately published as ebooks (and are currently available on Amazon). The third through fifth books in the series *haven't* been been published as ebooks and the modern reboot series (6 through 9) have all been.

1. Little Fuzzy by H. Beam Piper - Yes
2. Fuzzy Sapiens by H. Beam Piper - Yes
3. Fuzzies and Other People by H. Beam Piper - No
4. Fuzzy Bones by William Tuning - No
5. Golden Dream: A Fuzzy Odyssey by Ardath Mayhar - No
6. The Fuzzy Conundrum by Wolfgang Diehr - Yes
7. Fuzzy Nation by John Scalzi - Yes
8. Fuzzy Ergo Sum by Wolfgang Diehr - Yes
9. Caveat Fuzzy by Wolfgang Diehr - Yes

Comment: I wouldn't bother with Fuzzy Nation by Scalzi. It's a very bad re-write of Little Fuzzy. All the others are good.

Comment: IIRC *Fuzzies and Other People* was cleaned up/partially rewritten (by Carr?) for publication, so unlike the rest it may still be under copyright.

Comment: Until I can figure out how to store Kindle books in my backups and read them in other ereaders I'm not buying from Amazon.